# How to fix codenameone ios push error : P12 password is missing

Tags: codenameone

I am getting this error while pushing notifications to iOS device from server:

> Exception while generating certificate data, probably P12 password is missing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passwords must be specified.Oracle Java SDK does not support passwordless p12 certificates

I am sending all required parameters including the P12 certificate url & password provided by CN1.

How do I diagnose or fix this issue ?

The P12 certificate was generated using the CN1 wizard and I got an email with a link to it and the password. The push request is sent from a ASP.Net MVC application running on IIS web server. Android requests sent from the same server work just fine.

Comment: I'm assuming your P12 file has a password that isn't blank? If so how are you sending the push request exactly?